# Invoking a Click Event in a Web Browser without an Id?

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control, getelementbyid

How would I invoke a click event in a vb web browser without an id for the element?
Can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Get the HTML Control you want to click in a `HtmlElement` object. You don't have the ID, so you can't use `GetElementById`, but there are many others that can help you in getting the element of your interest. See the example below.
2. Use the `InvokeMember` method on the object to click it.

Here's an example:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim elements = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")   '' or whatever tag it is
    For Each element As HtmlElement In elements
        '' test here if this is the element of your interest.
        '' e.g.
        If element.GetAttribute("className") = "someclass" Then
            element.InvokeMember("click")   '' if found, click it!
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```